# How can I get Slick 3 to produce BIGSERIAL instead of GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY?

Tags: postgresql, slick, scalatra, slick-3.0

I'm getting up and running with Slick 3 in a Scalatra app, with PostgreSQL.  I'm able to read from a manually created table just fine, but I'm having trouble creating one via Slick.  When I print out the generated SQL, I see this:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table"
  (
     "id"   INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     "text" VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL
  );
```

that doesn't work, even manually entered into psql, generating an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GENERATED"
```

Ultimately this is what I think I need:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table"
  (
     "id"   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     "text" VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL
  );
```

In my build.scala, I have these dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.2",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
"com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.4.5",
```

application.conf has this:

```
postgres {
  driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  db {
    url = "jdbc:postgresql://db/mydb"
    driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    connectionPool = HikariCP
    user = postgres
    password = ""
  }
}
```

My bootstrap code has this:

```
import slick.backend.{DatabaseConfig, StaticDatabaseConfig}
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile

@StaticDatabaseConfig("file:src/main/resources/application.conf#postgres")
class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  override def init(context: ServletContext) {
    val dbConfig = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("postgres")
    MyDAO.db = dbConfig.db
    context.mount(new MyController, "/*")
  }
  ...
}
```

MyDAO has:

```
var db: Database = null

class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String)](tag, "my_table") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def text = column[String]("text", O.SqlType("varchar(4096)"))

  def * = (id, text)
}

val myTable = TableQuery[MyTable]

val createTable = myTable.schema.create

def createAllTables() = {
  createTable.statements.foreach(println)
  db.run(createTable)
}
```

And the controller is successfully calling that createAllTables function, without errors.  I haven't confirmed the error via PostgreSQL logs directly because I'm having some fits configuring the Docker container it's running in, but I have confirmed the ability to query.

What must I tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And as usual, I answer my own StackOverflow question within minutes of posting it.  The issue was that I was importing a deprecated JdbcDriver in my data access object, where the schema.create action was being prepared.  I had to replace this:

```
import slick.driver.JdbcDriver.api._
```

with this:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
```

And now it's generating something PostgreSQL likes:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_table" 
  ( 
     "id"   SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     "text" VARCHAR(4096) NOT NULL 
  )
```